# android weird (at least for me) behaviour of control after scaling / doesn't accept input in it's whole area

Tags: android, input, view, scaling

This should be simple but I can't find a solution:
I have a custom view and it scales to 200% if the user clicks on it. It stays on that size until the user clicks on it again.

That works, but only in the old (=smaller) area of the control. It seems that it is not existent (although it is shown) in the area which it now covers.
Do I need to call some method after scaling to fix my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You mean that you can only click on the old part of it?  Can you show some information about the layout, what is around your custom view?  And a code snippet of how you are scaling? Are you onMeasure, onLayout?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I can only click on the old part of it. There is a wheel (same with other controls) on it which is animated - this does redraw sometimes in the new part, but most of the time it doesn't. Just as a detail. My custom view is placed in a RelativeView. This is the animation which I'm calling to scale: <scale
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:fromXScale="1"
 android:toXScale="2" 
 android:fromYScale="1"
 android:toYScale="2"
 android:duration="300"
 android:fillAfter="true"
 android:fillEnabled="true"/>
That is all I'm doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigating I am quite sure this is a bug in android 2.3.1.
As a workaround I set the new size of the view at the end of the ScaleAnimation manually.