# Android navigation drawer screenshot

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I implemented a screenshot function triggered by an item in my navigation drawer. It works fine, but I want to make an screenshot of the whole page I see *without* the navigation drawer at that moment.

I used the layout suggested in the google tutorial to implement the navigation drawer:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Main content view-->
    <FrameLayout

            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!--Navigation Drawer-->
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="@color/sw21Background"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My code starts in the overridden listener method:

```
/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position, view); // my code, e.g. takeScreenshot(view);
    }
}

     /**
     * Swap fragments in the main content view
     */
    private void selectItem(int position, View view) {
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

        if (position == 0) {
            ...
        } else if (position == 3) {
            //Feedback
            // TODO get proper view of current page not the navigation drawer
            Bitmap bitmap = this.takeScreenShot(view.getRootView());
            Uri uri = saveBitmap(bitmap);
            sendEmail(uri);
        } ...

        //Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        //Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(navigationItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }
```

The current view is partially hidden by the navigation bar, so the following code also takes a shot of the bar:

```
private Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                    view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

I tried to use the view nested in the FrameLayout (content), but it does not cover the action bar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321344/android-animation-wait-until-finished

This should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and fixed it like this:

```
        View screenshotView = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        Bitmap bitmap = this.takeScreenShot(screenshotView);
        Uri uri = saveBitmap(bitmap);
        sendEmail(uri);
```

R.id.content_frame is my mainframe where I inflate all Fragments. Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Close `NavigationDrawer` before taking screenshot in your `takeScreenShot` function. `mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`

```
private Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT); // Close Drawer Here
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
                    view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However, it doesnt work since closeDrawer executes after my logic within the overridden: onItemClick(...) method has finished.

Comment: @journeycorner do you want to show Drawer in screenshot?

Comment: no, i want to hide it. Purpose of this screenshot is to send a feedback e-mail with an attached screenshot - like a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right answer for that is to close the drawer and create an event handler for DrawerClosed, and on the Handler, you take the picture.

like this:

```
                    drawer.CloseDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Start);

                    //take silent screenshot
                    View rootView = Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.MainContainer);
                    drawer.DrawerClosed += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        Bitmap tmpPic = ShareHandler.TakeScreenShot(this); //TakeScreenShot(rootView); 
                        Java.IO.File imageSaved = ShareHandler.StoreScreenShot(tmpPic);
                        if (imageSaved != null)
                        {
                            ShareHandler.ShareImage(imageSaved, this,"com.whatsapp", "", "ScreenShot Taken from: " + "Wharever");
                        }
                    };
```