# ImageView Animation Translation

Tags: java, android

I'm testing out an animation on an `ImageView`.
I want the `ImageView` to move down 1500 in 1 second and then up 1500 in the next 1 second (back to where is started).
For some reason the imageView only ever does one translation and not the other. Why is this?

```
imageView.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(1000);

imageView.animate().translationYBy(-1500).setDuration(1000);
```

Another example:

```
imageView.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(1000);
imageView.animate().translationXBy(-1500).setDuration(1000);
```

This does the X and Y animations at the same time, I thought it would do the Y animation over 1 second and then do the X animation over the next second.

Can someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: This happens because both animations try to run at the same time. I suggest using a timer to wait for the first animation to finish (Don't do this on the UI thread), or use an [animation listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21122591/1270000) to run the next animation after the first one finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sazzad. How come a counter.setTranslationY(-1500); runs before a counter.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(1000); Why are they not trying to also run at the same time?

Comment: Is it because counter.setTranslationY(-1500); is not an animation?