# How to find animation is finished playing in android

Tags: android, animation, webview

Here is a simple code to  animate webview screen.  But the problem is, the screen get scrolled before the animation take place..but i need apply animation for current screen... how can i solve this?

here is my piece of Code

```
if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

     mWebView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.page_slide_left_in));  
     mWebView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.page_slide_left_out));

    mWebView.scrollBy(mWebView.getWidth(),0);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `android.view.animation.Animation` class (returned by `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation` has a nested interface called `AnimationListener` which you can use to determine when an animation has completed. Specifically, you'd be interested in implementing the `onAnimationEnd` method of the listener interface.

Obviously, you'd also have to call `setAnimationListener` on the `Animation` instance returned by `loadAnimation`.

Comment: @vnshetty There's also the option of overriding the `View` class' `onAnimationEnd` method, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend/5110476#5110476).

Personally, I've only used the method in my answer to detect the end of an animation, so I'm not aware of any other methods without having to go search for them.