# How to trigger an animation when a layout animation ends

Tags: android, layout, animation, 3d

I have a custom 3d flip that needs to get the root view to access the two views that are flipped, like this: v.startAnimation(new Flip3D(v));

Then, I have a grid layout with a GridLayoutAnimationController that loads a simple scale animation.

What i'm trying, is to trigger the 3d flip on each child when the layout animation ends.

Is it possible? How can I get the view that has ended the animation to start the 3d animation?

What I tried is to attach an animation listener to the scale animation and count how many times onAnimationEnd gets called. Each time a view of the grid finish the animation I access the grid child at that position to start the 3d flip animation but, it has no effect.

Any idea?

Comment: if you could publish your flip3d code, I would love that...

Comment: @Snicolas  : if you want a class for Flip3d Animation , i have it , but how i could publish it without anyQuestion or something ,??? 
@ferdy182 : you can setAnimationListener as Cata said , and on the method onAnimationEnd() , launch your flip3D Animation

Comment: You can share your code on one of the services: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/top-5-places-to-share-code-quickly/ and paste link to snippet here :)

Comment: Hi, my 3d flip code is based on this http://goo.gl/nrX1K
On the other hand, what I need is a reference to the view that has ended the animation, in order to apply the 3d flip, because I need a reference to the view, to switch between views using the 3d flip, but only when it has ended

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `onAnimationEnd()` see here the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAnimationEnd%28%29

Here is an example how to use it: [android animation is not finished in onAnimationEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend)

Something like:

```
mAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                       //Functionality here
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm already using onAnimationEnd, but it gets called for every cell of the grid view but without a reference to the view that has ended, but, even counting how many times it gets called, I can't start the 3d flip on the result view of the call grid.getChildAt(i) or grid.getAdapter().getView(i,null,null)