# Between "end of translate animation" and re-positioning of the layout, there is a unexpected "jump".How to avoid it?

Tags: android

so I have the next problem with my app.I am using TranslateAnimation for my layout and after it ends I set for my layout new l,t,b,r, in order to replace it phisically,also.Here is the code:

```
package com.Borislav_Nazarski_SM;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener,AnimationListener {

    RelativeLayout L;
    ImageView imageView4;
    Animation inFromLeftAnimation,inFromRightAnimation;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        L = (RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
        imageView4 = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        imageView4.setOnClickListener(this);
        //animation that move the layout from top to 202px
        inFromLeftAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,202);
        inFromLeftAnimation.setDuration(12500);
        inFromLeftAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        inFromLeftAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        inFromLeftAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        inFromLeftAnimation.setFillBefore(false);
        inFromLeftAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
          //animation that move the layout back
        inFromRightAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,202,0);
        inFromRightAnimation.setDuration(12500);
        inFromRightAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        inFromRightAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
        inFromRightAnimation.setFillBefore(false);
        inFromRightAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        inFromRightAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==imageView4)
        {

            if(v.isSelected())
            {
                v.setSelected(false);
                L.clearAnimation();
        L.startAnimation(inFromRightAnimation);
        }
            else
            {
                v.setSelected(true);
                L.clearAnimation();
                L.startAnimation(inFromLeftAnimation);
            }
        }

   }
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(animation==inFromLeftAnimation){

            L.layout(0,0,800,606);

        }
        if(animation==inFromRightAnimation){

            L.layout(0,-202,800,404);

        }
    }
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

Here is the layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00FF00" android:orientation="horizontal" android:id="@+id/mainlayout" android:layout_height="606px" android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:id="@+id/imageView4" android:clickable="true" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3" android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"></ImageView>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_above="@+id/imageView3"></ImageButton>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="130px" android:layout_height="180px" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"></ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the problem is that after the animation reach it's end -there is a "jump" down or up depending on the animation - may be something with the positioning I am using L.layout(... does not work.Please,help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug with animationListeners. As a workaround you have to subclass your View and override onAnimationEnd there instead. See also [android animation is not finished in onAnimationEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750939/android-animation-is-not-finished-in-onanimationend)