# Click Listener behavior when two layouts get animated

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two buttons.When first button is pressed i am translating my layout layout to top and from the top of the screen another layout will come.But my issue is when came back to first layout the click events of the second layout still get fired at its previous position.So what is the Solution of it?I found a lot here on SO as well as on Google but still cannot get the right solution yet.So Please someone help me for my this issue.Thanks in Advance.

```
TranslateAnimation tr1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -1100);
        tr1.setDuration(1000);
        tr1.setFillAfter(true);
        layout_login.startAnimation(tr1);
        tr1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                layout_signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TranslateAnimation tr2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0,
                        -1100, 0);
                tr2.setDuration(1000);
                tr2.setFillAfter(true);
                tr2.setInterpolator(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
                layout_signup.startAnimation(tr2);

                tr2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        home_activity_btn_login.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: means r u expanding 1 layout and collapsing other layout?

Comment: do you want to do this with the help of expand and collapse animation?

Comment: @Pratik : well just want to do one layout is going up.after the layout touches the top of the phone screen i want to show another layout coming from the top of the phone Screen.I have done it with the help of translate animation but my problem is after translating i am able to click events of the second layout still get fired at its previous position.what is the solution of it?

Comment: i want to see your XML can you please post it?.

Comment: @Pratik :  i have done with java code not using XML.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31700/discussion-between-user1317-and-pratik)

Comment: i m sure it will useful to u.try and let me know.

Comment: @Pratik : why you delete your answer?

Comment: i thought it did not work for you.That's y i have deleted.

Comment: @Pratik : i tried it but layouts are not moving

Comment: dude not working??How r u passing the view?

Comment: @Pratik : like this..is it right?
View_login = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null);
  layout_signup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_signup);
  View_SignUp = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
    R.layout.include_layout_signup, null);
collapse(View_login);
expand(View_SignUp);

Comment: yup it's write way..but i m surprised why it is not working.

Comment: first check to simple view i mean not inflated view.I have tested this animations and they r working.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is a bug with the old animator schemes (I beleive a pretty well known bug, involving fill after not working sometimes).  Try using ObjectAnimator instead

Here is an example,

```
ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 0, 100f);
oa.setDuration(1000);
oa.start();
```

If you want to move in the Y direction, you can use translationY.  If you want to move in both directions, you need a translationX and translationY, and use an AnimatorSet to play simultaneously.

Check out this [comment to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188338/how-to-animate-a-views-translation#comment-14685257)  Using the old Animation API, apparently dispite fillAfter(true), the buttons click position remains the same.  This confirms your issue.  So just use the new API, and you should be in good shape.

Comment: I think this will help me to move my layout in X Co-Ordinate but if i want to move my layout to Y Co-Ordinate then what should i have to do? I think for that i will not help me. am I Right?

Comment: ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationY", 0, 5f); would do it

Comment: Check out my edit to the question.  I found another question that had the exact same issue.  My solution should solve, FYI