# Keep changes after animation, functionality-wise

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

So, I have a scale animation in my Android project. The scaling is done when a relative layout containing an image view is clicked and I want the changes to stay.

Now, I know about `anim.FillAfter = true;` and I've managed to keep the endstate of the animation. There's still a problem with it tho. Let's say I have a 400x600 px image that I scale down to 200x300 (x,y not changing positions). The image scales down when I click on on the relative layout containing the image. After the animation is over and the image seems to be in that 200x300 state. However, I can still launch the animation by clicking in the empty space left by the scaling (that 200 pixels right and 300 px bottom that the image used to fill). My best guess about that is that, visually, the changes are happening and persisting, but only visually.

Code-wise, this it's what it looks like:

UI builder:

```
CustomGestureListener container = new CustomGestureListener (this); <- Custom relative layout integrating GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener, GestureDetector.IOnDoubleTapListener and ScaleGestureDetector.IOnScaleGestureListener
ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
iv.SetImageDrawable (workingCopy);
iv.SetBackgroundColor (Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
iv.Clickable = false;
container.AddView (iv, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent));

GesturesExtension.Click(container).ActionEvent += delegate(GesturesExtension.State StateValue) {
            PTAnimationExtender.Scale(container, new System.Drawing.Size(container.Width, container.Height), new System.Drawing.Size((int)(container.Width / 2), (int)(container.Height / 2)), 2, delegate {
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                ad.SetMessage("View scaled");
                ad.Create().Show();
            });
        };
```

The scaling:

```
public static void Scale (this View view, Size Start, Size End, double DurationInSec, Action Callback)
{
    ScaleAnimation sa = new ScaleAnimation (((float)Start.Width) / ((float)view.Width), ((float)End.Width) / ((float)view.Width), ((float)Start.Height) / ((float)view.Height), ((float)End.Height) / ((float)view.Height)); 
    sa.Duration = (long)(DurationInSec * 1000);
    sa.FillAfter = true;
    sa.Interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator (2.5f);
    view.Animation = sa;
    view.Animation.AnimationEnd += delegate(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e) {
        if (Callback != null)
            Callback.Invoke ();
    };
    view.StartAnimation (view.Animation);
}
```

And lastly, the OnClick listener on the `CustomGestureListener`:

```
public class ClickClass
    {
        public delegate void Event (State StateValue);
        public event Event ActionEvent;

        public void CallEvent(State StateValue)
        {
            if (ActionEvent != null)
                ActionEvent (StateValue);
        }
    }
    ///<remarks>Detect a Click over your CustomGestureListener</remarks>
    public static ClickClass Click(this CustomGestureListener view)
    {
        ClickClass click = new ClickClass ();

        view.OnTapEvent += delegate(State state) {
            click.CallEvent (state);
        };

        return click;
    }
```

Something else I've tried is replacing the `FillAfter` option. On the `view.Animation.AnimationEnd` event handler I had a rescaling on the view. Something on these lines:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.LayoutParameters;
lp.Width = End.Width;
lp.Height = End.Height;
view.LayoutParameters = lp;
```

Which ended up having the result I wanted! (Keeping the endstate after the rescaling both visually and functionally). The issue I have with changing the layout parameter of the view is that when that happens the view has a visual glitch. As that layout params change executes, for a fraction of a second, the entire view rescales to a smaller version version of itself before taking the correct size.

Any solution for fixing this issue is welcomed, either by tackling the fill after or the visual glitch caused by the change in the layoutparams of the view... or anything else I could have missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up finding a workarround for the visual flickering when changing the layout parameters. As stated before, my problem was solved when applying the following on the animation end:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.LayoutParameters;
lp.Height = 350;
lp.Width = 150;
view.LayoutParameters = lp;
```

The issue with that was a visual flicking. But the visual flicking was being caused by the `AnimationEnd` being called before the animation was actually over. So... this fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110476