# Rotating a view and handling redraws

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using a `RotationAnimation` to rotate a custom view object (derived directly from `View`). The view object's `onDraw()` is called repeatedly during the animation, and then `onAnimationEnd` callback is called. In the callback I am updating the view's backing data object to record its new rotation.

The problem I am seeing is that the view object continues to have its `onDraw()` called *after* the `onAnimationEnd` callback has been called and has returned. This is a problem because, in the callback, I update values that cause the view to render its contents with a rotation. Since the animation is also still transforming the view, the end-result is that it briefly over-rotates before snapping back to the correct position as the rotation transform is removed.

So, if the animation causes the animated view's `onDraw()` to be called after `onAnimationEnd` is called, how can I determine when the animation has *really* finished so that I can update the backing object model at the appropriate time?

I'd be grateful for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone reading this question in the future, the solution to reliably detecting the end of the animation seems to be to override `onAnimationEnd()` on the `View` object being animated.

Further details can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110476/67316.